# Why does overriding __contains__ break OrderedDict.keys?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm subclasssing OrderedDict (Cpython, 2.7.3) to represent a datafile.  `__getitem__` pulls a field out of the datafile and sets it on the current instance similar to the code I've posted below.  now I would like to override `__contains__` to return `True` if the field is in the dictionary or in the file on the disk since it can be read either way.  However, this seems to break `OrderedDict`'s ability to inspect it's keys.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

dictclass = OrderedDict

class Foo(dictclass):
    def __getitem__(self,key):
        try:
            return dictclass.__getitem__(self,key)
        except KeyError:
            pass

        data = key*2
        self[key] = data
        return data

    def __contains__(self,whatever):
        return dictclass.__contains__(self,whatever) or 'bar' in whatever

a = Foo()
print a['bar']
print a.keys()
```

If you run the code above, you'll get this output:

```
barbar
[]
```

Note that if you change `dictclass = dict` in the above code, it still seems to work (giving the following output).

```
barbar
['bar']
```

Am I doing something horribly wrong?

Comment: I'm reading the [source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/collections.py) and I'm still having a hard time figuring this one out ...

Comment: I'm doing so and I think where is your problem: Take a look at `__setitem__` and `__iter__`.

Comment: @A.Rodas -- Yes, that's where I was looking.  Maybe I'm just too tired, but I was having a hard time keeping all the logic straight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**When `Foo.__contains__` is not defined**:

```
a['bar']
```

calls `Foo.__getitem__`, which executes

```
    self[key] = data
```

This calls `OrderedDict.__setitem__`, which is defined this way:

```
def __setitem__(self, key, value, PREV=0, NEXT=1, dict_setitem=dict.__setitem__):
    'od.__setitem__(i, y) <==> od[i]=y'
    # Setting a new item creates a new link at the end of the linked list,
    # and the inherited dictionary is updated with the new key/value pair.
    if key not in self:
        root = self.__root
        last = root[PREV]
        last[NEXT] = root[PREV] = self.__map[key] = [last, root, key]
    dict_setitem(self, key, value)
```

Since `Foo.__contains__` is not defined,

```
    if key not in self:
```

is True. So the key is properly added to `self.__root` and `self.__map`.

**When `Foo.__contains__` is defined**,

```
    if key not in self:
```

if False. So the key is not properly added to `self.__root` and `self.__map`.
`Foo.__contains__` effective fools `OrderedDict.__setitem__` into thinking that the `'bar'` key has already been added.

---

I found it helpful to play with the following code (adding print statements in `__setitem__` and `__iter__`):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

dictclass = OrderedDict

class Foo(dictclass):
    def __getitem__(self,key):
        try:
            return dictclass.__getitem__(self,key)
        except KeyError:
            pass

        data = key*2
        self[key] = data
        return data

    def __contains__(self,whatever):
        print('contains: {}'.format(whatever))
        return dictclass.__contains__(self,whatever) or 'bar' in whatever

    def __setitem__(self, key, value, PREV=0, NEXT=1, dict_setitem=dict.__setitem__):
        'od.__setitem__(i, y) <==> od[i]=y'
        # Setting a new item creates a new link at the end of the linked list,
        # and the inherited dictionary is updated with the new key/value pair.
        print('key not in self: {}'.format(key not in self))
        if key not in self:
            root = self._OrderedDict__root
            last = root[PREV]
            last[NEXT] = root[PREV] = self._OrderedDict__map[key] = [last, root, key]
        dict_setitem(self, key, value)

    def __iter__(self):
        'od.__iter__() <==> iter(od)'
        # Traverse the linked list in order.
        NEXT, KEY = 1, 2

        root = self._OrderedDict__root
        curr = root[NEXT]
        print('curr: {}'.format(curr))
        print('root: {}'.format(root)) 
        print('curr is not root: {}'.format(curr is not root))

        while curr is not root:
            yield curr[KEY]
            curr = curr[NEXT]

a = Foo()
print a['bar']
# barbar

print a.keys()
# ['bar']
```

---

Notice that you can avoid this problem by making `Foo` a subclass of `collections.MutableMapping` and delegating most of its behavior to a `OrderedDict` attribute:

```
import collections
dictclass = collections.OrderedDict

class Foo(collections.MutableMapping):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._data = dictclass(*args, **kwargs)
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._data[key] = value
    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self._data[key]
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._data)
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._data)

    def __getitem__(self,key):
        try:
            return self._data[key]
        except KeyError:
            pass

        data = key*2
        self[key] = data
        return data

    def __contains__(self,whatever):
        return dictclass.__contains__(self,whatever) or 'bar' in whatever
```

which yields

```
a = Foo()
print a['bar']
# barbar

print a.keys()
# ['bar']
```

even with `__contains__` defined.

Comment: Thanks.  That's it -- I was spending too much time focusing on `self.__root` and how it gets initialized -- Thinking -- `self.__root = root = []; root[:] = [root,root,None]`  What is going on??!??! :X

Comment: My method of figuring things out is very low-brow -- it generally consists of lots of print statements. :)

Answer (score 2):

What breaks your code is the `or 'bar' in whatever`. If you remove it, it will work as with the change `dictclass = dict` you mention.

The `__setitem__` implementation of `OrderedDict` is this:

```
def __setitem__(self, key, value, dict_setitem=dict.__setitem__):
    'od.__setitem__(i, y) <==> od[i]=y'
    # Setting a new item creates a new link at the end of the linked list,
    # and the inherited dictionary is updated with the new key/value pair.
    if key not in self:
        root = self.__root
        last = root[0]
        last[1] = root[0] = self.__map[key] = [last, root, key]
    return dict_setitem(self, key, value)
```

So with `self["bar"] = "barbar"`, the condition should be False, but it is True even before inserting any item. Thus, the key isn' added to `self.__root` which is used in `OrderedDict.__iter__`:

```
def __iter__(self):
    'od.__iter__() <==> iter(od)'
    # Traverse the linked list in order.
    root = self.__root
    curr = root[1]                                  # start at the first node
    while curr is not root:
        yield curr[2]                               # yield the curr[KEY]
        curr = curr[1]                              # move to next node
```

Since the code for retrieving the values uses this iterator and `self.__root` does not contain `"bar"`, this concrete key cannot be returned in the values.

Comment: Yep, this is it.  Thanks.  +1.  Of course, in my code, the `or 'bar' in whatever` is something more complicated that I don't *want* to remove.  I think that hacking around OrderedDict to get it to work properly is going to be too difficult.  I suppose I'll just subclass a regular dict and keep a separate `__order` list.

Comment: @mgilson: Maybe let `Foo` *have-a* `OrderedDict`, instead of *be-a* `OrderedDict`?

Comment: @unutbu -- I want it to be a mapping type so that I can unpack it ... I can keep track of the order myself.

Comment: @mgilson: Yes, I think you can do that by making `Foo` a subclass of `collections.MutableMapping`, but delegating stuff like `__getitem__`, and `__contains__` to an `OrderedDict` instance (stored in an attribute). The `OrderedDict` behavior will remain pristine, while you can do your own thing in `__getitem__` and `__contains__`.

Comment: @mgilson: If you subclass `MutableMapping` at a minimum you must override `__getitem__`, `__setitem__`, `__delitem__`, `__iter__`, `__len__` and `__contains__`.